# Is my GPU dying?

Tags: linux, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I temporarily disable ECC memory protection on a NVIDIA K20m (device 0 in my node) and now I cannot bring it back to work again.
Before that it was working properly with ECC enabled.
So, here is what I did:
I disabled ECC with

```
nvidia-smi -i 0 --ecc-config=0
```

and rebooted. When it came up it showed 100% GPU utilization and it wouldn't start any kernels (it actually already failed when creating the context). The reason was a double bit error. I reset it with

```
nvidia-smi -i 0 --reset-ecc-errors=0
```

and rebooted the node. After the reboot the device utilization was 0% and I could start jobs as usual. A few hours later the device showed again a 100% GPU utilization. This time it didn't report a double bit error (not even a single bit error). However, since I couldn't run any job I rebooted the node and it came up with 100% GPU utilization, I can't use it, but reports no bit errors. What's the matter this it?

```
GPU 0000:02:00.0
    Product Name                : Tesla K20m
    Display Mode                : Disabled
    Persistence Mode            : Enabled
    Driver Model
        Current                 : N/A
        Pending                 : N/A
    Serial Number               : 0324512044699
    GPU UUID                    : GPU-9bfe1aba-1628-a406-3ed5-2af49462a997
    VBIOS Version               : 80.10.11.00.0B
    Inforom Version
        Image Version           : 2081.0208.01.07
        OEM Object              : 1.1
        ECC Object              : 3.0
        Power Management Object : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                 : Compute
        Pending                 : Compute
    PCI
        Bus                     : 0x02
        Device                  : 0x00
        Domain                  : 0x0000
        Device Id               : 0x102810DE
        Bus Id                  : 0000:02:00.0
        Sub System Id           : 0x101510DE
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max             : 2
                Current         : 2
            Link Width
                Max             : 16x
                Current         : 16x
    Fan Speed                   : N/A
    Performance State           : P0
    Clocks Throttle Reasons
        Idle                    : Not Active
        User Defined Clocks     : Not Active
        SW Power Cap            : Not Active
        HW Slowdown             : Not Active
        Unknown                 : Not Active
    Memory Usage
        Total                   : 4799 MB
        Used                    : 12 MB
        Free                    : 4787 MB
    Compute Mode                : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                     : 100 %
        Memory                  : 0 %
    Ecc Mode
        Current                 : Enabled
        Pending                 : Enabled
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
        Aggregate
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
    Temperature
        Gpu                     : 30 C
    Power Readings
        Power Management        : Supported
        Power Draw              : 49.51 W
        Power Limit             : 225.00 W
        Default Power Limit     : 225.00 W
        Min Power Limit         : 150.00 W
        Max Power Limit         : 225.00 W
    Clocks
        Graphics                : 758 MHz
        SM                      : 758 MHz
        Memory                  : 2600 MHz
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                : 705 MHz
        Memory                  : 2600 MHz
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                : 758 MHz
        SM                      : 758 MHz
        Memory                  : 2600 MHz
    Compute Processes           : None
```

Comment: seems strange; never spotted anything like this. Even though it may not help solve the problem, try re-installing your drivers, maybe?

Comment: I guess you already tried the obvious to just scrap and reinstall everything? I mean, uhm, I know little about hardware, so my approach is always to make absolutely sure the software - what I do understand - should work. And then I'll possibly declare the piece broken until contradicted by a more knowledgeable opinion.

Comment: I've looked over it, as well as spent some time researching this issue and its causes. It does appear that the best solution is to replace the hardware.

Comment: Did you try to reset CMOS already?

Answer (score 2):

**Is my GPU dying?**

I say it's already dead.  It's no longer *reporting* bit errors because you turned off the thing that detects them. (ECC *detects* more than it can correct.)  However, it may be the memory on the card (or the physical card itself) that's developed a fault.

There's two other suspects before I'd chuck it in the "recycle" bin: cooling, and power supply.  Cooling is easy enough to check; power, not so much.